# Stop Credit Memo applying itself to Sales Invoice at create stage

Tags: netsuite

When creating a Credit Memo from an open Sales Invoice, how do I stop the Credit Memo automatically applying itself to the Sales Invoice?

This is not to do with the Auto Apply tick box which applies the credit memo to the first available Sales Invoice rather than the Sales Invoice referenced.

I wish to stop ALL Applying of the Credit Memo at the create stage.  I only wish to be able to apply Credit Memos during a Customer Payment.

Comment: How are you creating the Credit Memo? Is it through "Credit" button on Invoice record? If so, there is no standard way to remove the Invoice on the Created From field of the Credit Memo. You need to hide the standard Credit Memo and replace it with a custom Credit button via Workflow.

Comment: Yes that is how the Credit Memo is created.  I want to keep the Created From field. 
It's the Apply sublist section where I want to stop it. Thanks.